# XSLT fails when envelop is added

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a perfectly working XSL (thanks to you / StackOverflow):
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NgtZRc

**Input xml**

```
<Containers xmlns="https://www.uniconcreation.com/2021/IvenzaShippingContainer">
    <Container>
        <Name>INTERIEUR1</Name>
        <Number>1</Number>
        <SSCC>111</SSCC>
        <SubContainers>
            <Container>
                <Id>I1371851</Id>
                <SalesOrderNumber>2012231</SalesOrderNumber>
                <ProductionOrderNumber>I2017658</ProductionOrderNumber>
                <Name>ACCESSOIRE1</Name>
                <Barcode>181001371851</Barcode>
                <Items>
                    <Item>
                        <Id>I8709475</Id>
                        <SalesOrderRowId>I671068</SalesOrderRowId>
                        <SalesOrderRowExternalReference>1</SalesOrderRowExternalReference>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <Id>I8709476</Id>
                        <SalesOrderRowId>I671068</SalesOrderRowId>
                        <SalesOrderRowExternalReference>1</SalesOrderRowExternalReference>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    </Item>
                </Items>
            </Container>
            <Container>
                <Id>I1371852</Id>
                <SalesOrderNumber>2012231</SalesOrderNumber>
                <ProductionOrderNumber>I2017658</ProductionOrderNumber>
                <Name>PANEEL1</Name>
                <Barcode>181001371852</Barcode>
                <Items>
                    <Item>
                        <Id>I8709492</Id>
                        <SalesOrderRowId>I671068</SalesOrderRowId>
                        <SalesOrderRowExternalReference>1</SalesOrderRowExternalReference>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    </Item>
                </Items>
            </Container>
        </SubContainers>
    </Container>
```

**XSL**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="https://www.uniconcreation.com/2021/IvenzaShippingContainer" xmlns="https://www.uniconcreation.com/2021/IvenzaShippingContainer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="Containers">
      <xsl:variable name="sscc" select="Container/SSCC"/>
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:for-each select="//Container">
            <xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor::*)"/>
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="$level = 1">
                  <xsl:copy>
                     <xsl:copy-of select="Id"/>
                     <xsl:copy-of select="SalesOrderNumber"/>
                     <xsl:copy-of select="ProductionOrderNumber"/>
                     <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
                     <xsl:copy-of select="Type"/>
                     <xsl:copy-of select="Number"/>
                     <xsl:copy-of select="SSCC"/>
                     <xsl:copy-of select="Barcode"/>
                     <xsl:copy-of select="StartedAt"/>
                     <xsl:copy-of select="CompletedAt"/>
                     <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="SubContainers">
                           <Items>
                              <xsl:for-each select="SubContainers">
                                 <Item>
                                    <Id>
                                       <xsl:value-of select="Container[1]/Id"/>
                                    </Id>
                                    <SalesOrderRowId>
                                       <xsl:value-of select="Container[1]/Items/Item[1]/SalesOrderRowId"/>
                                    </SalesOrderRowId>
                                    
                                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                                 </Item>
                              </xsl:for-each>
                           </Items>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                           <xsl:copy-of select="Items"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                     </xsl:choose>
                  </xsl:copy>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Containers xmlns="https://www.uniconcreation.com/2021/IvenzaShippingContainer">
   <Container>
      <Name>INTERIEUR1</Name>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <SSCC>111</SSCC>
      <Items>
         <Item>
            <Id>I1371851</Id>
            <SalesOrderRowId>I671068</SalesOrderRowId>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
         </Item>
      </Items>
   </Container>
</Containers>
```

**Especially the xpath-default-namespace helped me preventing getting an empty  xmlns=""* for the Items Literal

But then I found out SAP PI puts an envelop around my message:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
       <ns0:Message1>
    <Containers xmlns="https://www.uniconcreation.com/2021/IvenzaShippingContainer">
            <Container>
                <Name>INTERIEUR1</Name>
                <Number>1</Number>
                <SSCC>111</SSCC>
                <SubContainers>
                    <Container>
                        <Id>I1371851</Id>
                        <SalesOrderNumber>2012231</SalesOrderNumber>
                        <ProductionOrderNumber>I2017658</ProductionOrderNumber>
                        <Name>ACCESSOIRE1</Name>
                        <Barcode>181001371851</Barcode>
                        <Items>
                            <Item>
                                <Id>I8709475</Id>
                                <SalesOrderRowId>I671068</SalesOrderRowId>
                                <SalesOrderRowExternalReference>1</SalesOrderRowExternalReference>
                                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                            </Item>
                            <Item>
                                <Id>I8709476</Id>
                                <SalesOrderRowId>I671068</SalesOrderRowId>
                                <SalesOrderRowExternalReference>1</SalesOrderRowExternalReference>
                                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                            </Item>
                        </Items>
                    </Container>
                    <Container>
                        <Id>I1371852</Id>
                        <SalesOrderNumber>2012231</SalesOrderNumber>
                        <ProductionOrderNumber>I2017658</ProductionOrderNumber>
                        <Name>PANEEL1</Name>
                        <Barcode>181001371852</Barcode>
                        <Items>
                            <Item>
                                <Id>I8709492</Id>
                                <SalesOrderRowId>I671068</SalesOrderRowId>
                                <SalesOrderRowExternalReference>1</SalesOrderRowExternalReference>
                                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                            </Item>
                        </Items>
                    </Container>
                </SubContainers>
            </Container>
    </Containers>
       </ns0:Message1>
    </ns0:Messages>
```

And I ended up with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Containers xmlns="https://www.uniconcreation.com/2021/IvenzaShippingContainer"
            xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge"/>
```

I tried prefixing all namespaces but I hope there's another way :(

Required output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Messages xmlns:ns0="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
   <ns0:Message1>
<Containers xmlns="https://www.uniconcreation.com/2021/IvenzaShippingContainer">
   <Container>
      <Name>INTERIEUR1</Name>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <SSCC>111</SSCC>
      <Items>
         <Item>
            <Id>I1371851</Id>
            <SalesOrderRowId>I671068</SalesOrderRowId>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
         </Item>
      </Items>
   </Container>
</Containers>
   </ns0:Message1>
</ns0:Messages>
```

Kind regards,

Mike

Comment: Your assumption about what `xpath-default-namespace` does is incorrect. To prevent an empty namespace declaration on a literal result element, you must put it in the same namespace as its parent element that you copied from the source. And if you want the original wrappers to be included, you must have a template that will copy them too.

Comment: Thanks! If I remove the xpath-default-namespace statement I think I have to prefix all elements ( xmlns:ucc="https://www.uniconcreation.com/2021/IvenzaShippingContainer" ) because I just get plain text. Prefixing works but then my results / combined with $level are messed up.

Comment: Yes, if you remove the `xpath-default-namespace` attribute, you will need to use a prefix when addressing the elements in the source XML. There is no effect on other aspects of the transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two wrapper elements, the value of `<xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor::*)"/>` is going to change so perhaps your check `<xsl:when test="$level = 1">` needs to be converted to `<xsl:when test="$level = 3">`.

You will also need to add some identity template to make sure the wrapper elements are copied.

Comment: `count(ancestor:: Container)` would probably make more sense. Or perhaps restricting the selection to `<xsl:for-each select="//Container[ancestor:: Container]">` could eliminate a lot of code.